# sql server: ROLLBACK inserted row only

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger that runs after the update record in the table A, add records to a table B
Now the table B has a trigger that works to ensure that the values ​​entered are correct, when there is a problem with it, the role of a trigger table B is to prevent the entry record (I can not use a unique index because the conditions are in other tables), but I want to avoid only the current record entry, as well as not to prevent the update is done in Table A and not the all good records in this transaction. 
the ROLLBACK function is canceling all open transactions.

Comment: Does SQL server have the concept of an autonomous transaction, like in Oracle?  Maybe that would work in your B trigger?

Comment: Just  Use a **Delete** sql command with join **inserted** variable 

     delete m from MyTable m inner join inserted i on i.ID = m.ID

Comment: you should throw more light like relation between table A and Table B .So that something like @user1737934 can be done.
also i think you can use Merge here.